# SLR(1) parser with epsilon transitions in the grammar

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, computer-science, grammar, formal-languages

I'm writing an SLR(1) parser from the following grammar:

```
1) S -> aSb
2) S -> cB
3) B -> cB
4) B -> ε
```

First of all, I started with finding the associated LR(0) automaton with the augmented grammar adding the `S' -> S` production and starting to compute the various states. The states that I found are:

I0 = {S'->•S, S->•aSb, S->•cB}
(I0, S) = I1; (I0, a) = I2; (I0, c) = I3;
I1 = {S'->S•}
I2 = {S->a•Sb, S->•aSb, S->•cB}
(I2, S) = I4; (I2, a) = I2; (I2, c) = I3
I3 = {S->c•B, B->•cB, B->•ε}
(I3, B) = I5; (I3, ε) = I6; (I3, c) = I7;
I4 = {S->aS•b}
(I4, b) = I8;
I5 = {S->cB•}
I6 = {B->ε•}
I7 = {B->c•B, B->•cB, B->•ε}
(I7, B) = I9; (I7, ε) = I6; (I7, c) = I7;
I8 = {S->aSb•}
I9 = {B->cB•}

And here there is the LR(0) automaton:

[Automaton Picture](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27406636/screen%202017-01-25%20alle%2023.55.40.png)

After that, I did the parser table (but I don't think it is needed in order to answer my question) so I have a doubt:
is the epsilon transition handled in the right way? I mean, I treated it as a normal character since we have to reduce by the rule number 4 at some point. If I'm wrong, how should I treat that transition? Thanks in advance, hoping this is helpful for other people as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no , there is no need to create the State I6

Confusion may have arise in `Y->Ɛ` . When you place a dot in the augmented productions for example `S->A.B` it means that `A` is completed and `B` is yet to be completed (by completion here means progress in parsing) . Similarly if you write `Y->.Ɛ` , it means `Ɛ` is yet to be over, but we also know that `Ɛ` is `null string` i.e nothing therefore `Y->.Ɛ` is interpreted as `Y->.`

you can use The [JFLAP Software](http://www.jflap.org/) and see it's [documentation about SLR(1)](http://jflap.org/tutorial/grammar/slr/index.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know the JFLAP Software but it seems very helpful for this kind of things. Also, thanks for the clarification about the epsilon transition, from what I understand I should apply the reduce directly in the state where I have the epsilon instead going to another state and then reduce there. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

NOT REQUIRED...
even i faced the same problem while removing left reccursion for the following grammar

`E->E+T|E-T|T`
the transformed rule looks like

`E->T X
X->+TX|-TX|*e*`

that doesnt matter as

x->.*e* and x->*e*. have no significance.Since moving the period before and after Epsilon is madman's job